# What is the need of HTTP methods like get,post in HTTP protocol?

Tags: http, post, get

can we not implement HTTP protocol using just request body and response body? For example, the URL will contain request, which will be sent to a server and will be mapped to some function on server and in response html/java script response will be sent across What is really the need of HTTP methods?

PS: Please read my comment on the first answer. That will clarify my question more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, these are the terminologies which describe the Attribute of HTML Request. It means that the request will tell you about the particular function that you perform in a certain task.
There are four basic functions which we also called CRUD operations.

1. Create => POST
2. Read => GET
3. Update => PUT
4. Delete => DELETE

As the above description shows that each an every Attribute have certain functionality.

Comment: "request will tell you about the particular function that you perform in a certain task" => This is something I don't understand. Why does the client need to tell server how to execute something. Client will only request for an URL and using URL, for example server can map it to a servlet and provide back the response. Why the client should ever need to provide how to execute something?.